# Is there a closed form for $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^2\log{j}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

#### Question

Is there a closed form for $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^2\log{j} = 1\times0 + 2^2\times\log{2} + 3^2\log{3} + \dots + n^2\log{n}$? I'm trying to look for the simplest $\Theta$ notation.

#### Attempt

Let $g(n)$ be the function in $\Theta (g(n))$. My current take is the following,

$g(n) = 1\times0 + 2^2\times\log{2} + 3^2\log{3} + \dots + n^2\log{n}$

For $g(n)$ to be $O(g(n))$, we can simplify it this way,

$$g(n) = 1\times0 + 2^2\times\log{2} + 3^2\log{3} + \dots + n^2\log{n}$$
$$g(n) = n^2\times 0 + n^2\times\log{2} + \dots + n^2\log{n}$$
$$g(n) = n^2 (\log{1} + \log{2} + \dots + \log{n})$$
$$g(n) = n^2(\log{n!})$$

But $n^2$ seems to get in the way of $g(n)$ also being $\Omega(g(n))$, if we pick something with lower power, e.g. $n^{1.5}$, then $g(n)$ will fail to be $O(g(n))$, thus it's impossible to simplify further.

Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: No idea. What is guaranteed is that your sum is asymptotic to $$ C + \int_1^n x^2 \log x dx,  $$ where you need to find out what the constant $C$ is. That is, $$ \sum_{j=1}^n j^2 \log j  - \int_1^n x^2 \log x dx $$ converges to a constant $C$

Comment: @WillJagy not for $\Theta$ notation, I don't think. And the integral is not necessarily off by a constant when the function is increasing, that theorem holds for decreasing functions.

Comment: By the way have you tried Maple or Mathematica? See my answer.

Comment: I will leave my earlier comment, although it is false in this case. For functions $f$ for which $f''$ is, eventually, always positive or always negative, the condition is that $f''$ be summable, meaning $f'$ has a finite limit as $x \rightarrow + \infty.$ So the constant thing does not apply to  $x^2 \log x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your function is monotone, it can be written as

$$\sum_{j=1}^nj^2\log j=\int_0^n t^2\log t\,dt+\theta(f(n)-f(0))$$

for some $-1\le\theta\le 1$. Then doing the integration, we get

$${1\over 3}\left(n^3\log(n^3)-1\right)+\theta(n^2\log n)=\Theta \left(n^3\log n\right)$$

---

In case you've never seen this result before, it's easy to see by using the left-hand and right-hand estimates on the integral, the former is less than the integral and the latter is greater.

To see this is simple, note

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} j^2\log j<\int_1^nt^2\log t\,dt <\sum_{j=1}^n j^2\log j$$

And so the difference between the sum and the integral is **bounded** by $|f(n)-f(0)|$ as

$$0<\int_1^nt^2\log t\,dt -\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}j^2\log j\le f(n)-f(0)$$

ergo

$$\left|\int_1^nt^2\log t\,dt -\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}j^2\log j\right|\le |f(n)-f(0)|$$

which is the absolute value of the difference of the sums, so it must be **equal** to $\theta(f(n)-f(0))=\theta n^2\log n$, since those are the only numbers bounded by $|f(n)-f(0)|$.

Comment: I've never seen that integral before. Where did you get the $\theta(f(n) - f(0))$ of the integral? Why is it there?

Comment: @ComputrScientist I've edited my answer for the completion.

Comment: Thanks. Completely makes sense.

Comment: Adam, we were both a little off on the asymptotic thing; it is not increasing or decreasing, it is whether the second derivative is summable/integrable, because $$ \int_{n - \frac{1}{2}}^{n + \frac{1}{2}} f(x) dx - f(n) \approx f''(n)/24 $$ Oh, and I canot recall what $\Theta$ means anyway.

Comment: Ah yes, that's right. Good find, @WillJagy. $\Theta$ means that the two functions have the same growth order up to a constant. i.e.

$$c|g|\le |f|\le C|g|.$$

Comment: @AdamHughes I just read my Calc textbook about series. Since the area of the integral of $\int_1^n f(n) > \sum_{j=0}^{n} j^2\log j$ which is the other way around. This is because the area of the rectangles formed by a discrete function are inside the curve of the integral.

Comment: @ComputrScientist check it out again, for $n=2,3,4$, that sum is larger than that integral.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a closed form

> $$ S =-\zeta'  \left( -2 \right) +\zeta_1' \left( -2,n+1 \right), $$

where $\zeta(x)$ and $\zeta(x,a)$ are the [zeta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and the [Hurwitz zeta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) functions. Note that $\zeta_1'(s,a)$ is the derivative w.r.t. the first argument. Here is an example

> $$ \sum_{k=1}^{10} j^2\ln(j) \approx 776.2476538  $$

and with the formula is

> $$ S \approx 776.2476539 .$$

**Added:** Here is a formula for a more general case in terms of the zeta and hurwitz zeta functions

> $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} j^{s}\ln(j)^{m}= \lim_{\alpha \to s } \zeta^{(m)}_{\alpha}( - \alpha ) + \zeta^{(m)}_{\alpha} \left( -\alpha,n+1 \right)  $$

Comment: Could you add the derivation for these?